# Request execution time WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout

I have my WCF service in which one line of code is problematic - 1 in ~50 requests, this line of code is executing without end and when that happens, WCF service is hanging until it timeouts. Since it has:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

every other request to this WCF is getting:

> "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to xxx. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down)."

for couple of minutes since the service is hanging.
Is there a way to control how long the execution of WCF method is taking and abort it, if it takes too long?

Comment: Does the operation in question have a return or is it a void?

Comment: It's a void method

Comment: You could change the time out, but if you never get a response then the application will hang for a long period of time.  It is better to use a sniffer like fiddler to attempt to find real root cause of issue.

Comment: The issue is that the line of code I'm using is from third party library, which has unmanaged code. That's why wcf hangs. I can't set timeouts, since the requests to the service are queued.

Comment: And can I assume that the reason the service is a singleton is that you have a requirement for ordered delivery/processing?

Comment: Yes, the third party library I'm using is not doing well with concurrency.

Comment: But the point being not about concurrency, but about ordering. Are the order in which calls are processed have to be the same order that the calls are made? Or can calls be processed in a different order to which they were made?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, they don't have to be in order.